# Laravel appending JSON object when filtering columns with a given value

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a search bar to allow users to:

(1) filter two tables with a given value,

(2) and also appending a 'status' column inside each 'row'

I did the first part like following:

```
public function getFilterBooks($input)
{
    $books = DB::table('books')
    ->join('categories', 'books.cat_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->where('b_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
    ->orWhere('b_author', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
    ->orWhere('cat_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
    ->get();
 }

return Response::json($books);
```

The JSON results returns fine:

```
[ { "id" : 1,
    "b_name" : "foo Name",
    "b_author" : "bar author",
    "cat_name" : "foobar cat",
  },
  { "id" : 2,
    "b_name" : "foo Name2",
    "b_author" : "bar author2",
    "cat_name" : "foobar cat2",
  }
 ]
```

However, I want to add some logical attribute here, such as when the **b_author** name is equal to the logged-in user **fullname**, then show the status as **true**, else **false**

Something like this: (Obviously it won't work)

```
if($books.b_author == Auth::user()->fullname){
  //set status as 'true'
}
```

Add should show something like this:

```
[ { "id" : 1,
    "b_name" : "foo Name",
    "b_author" : "bar author",
    "cat_name" : "foobar cat",
    "status" : true
  },
  { "id" : 2,
    "b_name" : "foo Name2",
    "b_author" : "bar author2",
    "cat_name" : "foobar cat2",
    "status" : false
  }
 ]
```

So the JSON result returns differently depending on the logged in user.

Comment: Well, i thought best way would be looping each element before convert into json to add another element to result.

Comment: you can use array function first : array_column($books,'b_author') and than in_array

Comment: @SafoorSafdar Can you give an example how would you do that?

Comment: @kamlesh.bar Can you give an example how would you do that?

Comment: @RobertM.Tijerina Please take a look to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be solve through eloquent model, please have a look my solution used in a project.

For the simple of the solution I just override the `toArray()` method.

For elxample:

```
class Example extends \Eloquent {
    //...
    public function toArray(){
        $array = parent::toArray();
        $array['status'] = ($array['b_author'] == Auth::user()->fullname)?true:false; 
        //just updating to required attribute result
        return $array;
    }
}
```

And whenever i call this model using:

```
Example::all()->toArray()
```

which will add automatically a element to all element of array.

**Update**

Another way to handle logical attribute in a model:

In order to force your attribute to be returned in the array, add it as a key to the $attributes array.

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $attributes = array(
        'status' => '',
    );

    public function getStatusCode()
    {
        return ....
    }
}
```

**Update-1**

As per the 5.1.

```
class User extends Eloquent {
 protected $appends = array('status');

    public function getStatusAttribute() {
      return 'someStatus';
   }
}
```

If you still face something confusing to resolve it let me know.

Comment: It works alright. But I was just wondering isn't it better to handle all logical stuff in a controller instead of in a model, in this case?

Comment: Well, logical stuff can handle through Repository Methods if and only when you need more than provided functioned. but in such cases you can easlly manage through given method or by extend them.

Comment: This is actually a really bad way to accomplish it. What if user decides to use the status for something else somewhere else in the future? I updated my answer according to this.

Comment: @HakanAktaş, i didn't get your point. can you explain further, so i can explain further to you....

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use other members' posts at all, your query is wrong. Should be like this:

```
$books = DB::table('books')
    ->join('categories', 'books.cat_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->where(function ($clause) {
        $clause->where('b_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
            ->orWhere('cat_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
    })
    ->where('b_author', Auth::id())
    ->get();
```

If you *do* use them hovewer, add this two piece of code to your model:

```
protected $appends = [ 'status' ];
```

-

```
public function getStatusAttribute()
{
    return $this->b_author == Auth::user()->fullname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the easiest way would be to do it in the database and add a select clause, something like this:

```
public function getFilterBooks($input)
{
    $books = DB::table('books')
    ->join('categories', 'books.cat_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->select(
        ['*', DB::raw('books.b_author = :username as status')], 
        [Auth::user()->fullname]
    )
    ->where('b_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
    ->orWhere('b_author', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
    ->orWhere('cat_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%')
    ->get();
}

return Response::json($books);
```

The reason for putting the `Auth::user()->fullname` in a separate array is because we want to escape it properly even though it's used in a `DB::raw()` query. And since you want all of the regular columns, we add the `'*'` to the select array as well.

Edit: explanation as requested:

When we do `select x = y as z ...` in SQL, we compare x with y, and z is set to 1 if they're equal, or 0 if they're not.

So in `books.b_author = :username as status`, we're saying "compare the b_author column from the table books with the value :username". But `:username` is just a placeholder for a value we'll insert later. That's what we do in the second array, `[Auth::user()->fullname]` - we replace `:username` with the logged-in user's fullname value.

That way, you can make the comparison directly in the query without any hassle in php afterwards to manipulate the results array.

Comment: Can you explain `DB::raw('books.b_author = :username as status')]` here? what is `= :username`?

Comment: It gives me: `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters` error, but it works with `DB::raw('books.b_author = ' . Auth::user()->fullname . ' as status')`

Comment: Ah, right, been a while since I did this myself... try replacing the `:username` with `?`. If that doesn't work, there's something else in the query that confuses the parameter bindings.

Comment: Alright, there's something else in the query messing with it then. I've tried both ways in a toy example on a database of my own, and they work great. The theory is solid, though - I can only advise you to try around with it and see if you can get it to work.